# How to pass variables to nested functions in cProfile's runctx()

Tags: python, cprofile

I'm trying to profile some code, but it has nested function calls.

It looks something like this:

```py
### user.py
class MyFlaskAPI:
  def get(self):
        page = 1
        pagesize = 100
        offset = 0

        user = get_user()
        results = paginate(user, page=page, pagesize=pagesize, offset=offset)

        return results

## paginate.py
def paginate(user, page=1, pagesize=100, offset=0):
        query = session.query(Foo).filter_by(ninja_id=user.org.ninja_id)
        results = # do some extra work
        return results
```

I am using cProfile's `runctx()` method. This particular function is within a request context, and looks like this:

```py
user = <SQLAlchemy user object>

with app.test_request_context():
        cProfile.runctx('MyFlaskAPI.get()', dict(MyFlaskAPI=MyFlaskAPI()), dict(user=user))
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error:

```py
query = session.query(Foo).filter_by(ninja_id=user.org.ninja_id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'organization'
```

I have also tried passing the user as a global, like this:

```py
with app.test_request_context():
        cProfile.runctx('MyFlaskAPI.get()', dict(MyFlaskAPI=MyFlaskAPI(), user=user), None)
```

In both cases I get the same error.

This leads me to believe that the `user` in the `filter_by` clause is `None`. However, I am trying to pass the user object as a global in `runctx()`. I must be doing something wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT: The issue had to do with the `get_user()` call. I thought I could override the user variable by passing in the user directly, but that is not the case. This issue is now resolved.